Quasilinear PDE with initial value
I want to solve the following PDE:

$x_1u_{x_1}+x_2u_{x_2} = 2; u|_{x_1=x_2}=0$

For the characteristic equations I have:
$$\frac {dx_1}{ds} = x_1$$
$$\frac {dx_2}{ds} = x_2$$
$$\frac {du}{ds} = 2$$
Applying the initial conditions, I have that $x_1(0) = r, x_2(0) = r, u(0) = 0$. Therefore:
$$x_1 = re^s$$
$$x_2 = re^s$$
$$u = 2s$$
I attempted writing $s = \ln\frac {x_1+x_2}{2r}$ or $2s = \ln\frac {x_1x_2}{r^2}$ and then tried to eliminate $r$ but I failed in both cases. Any help would be much appreciated.

The characteristic equations can be rewritten as
$$
\frac{dx_1}{x_1}\stackrel{(a)}{=}\frac{dx_2}{x_2}\stackrel{(b)}{=}\frac{du}{2}. \tag{1}
$$
Solving equations $(a)$ and $(b)$ we obtain
$$
x_2=C_1x_1\quad\text{and}\quad u=2\ln|x_2|+C_2, \tag{2}
$$
hence the general solution to the PDE is
$$
u(x_1,x_2)=2\ln|x_2|+f\!\left(\frac{x_2}{x_1}\right), \tag{3}
$$
where $f(\cdot)$ is an arbitrary differentiable function. To determine it, we use the condition $u|_{x_1=x_2}=0$, or
$$
2\ln|x_2|+f(1)=0. \tag{4}
$$
Since $x_2$ is arbitrary, Eq. $(4)$ doesn't have a solution. It follows that the PDE does not have a solution satisfying the condition $u|_{x_1=x_2}=0$.
